# Validation Form hasError AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to create a Form Validation with AngularJS,
and I ended up finding a condition using ng-class that I can not understand, can anyone tell me why here in this situation they are using ng-class like this? With a map and an array right after, I can not figure out how to do for the 'has-error' class to be enabled:

```
<div ng-if="conditionItem.field.id"
     ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[field.hasError]"
     dynamic
     input-router
     source="conditionItem.field"
     required ng-model="conditionItem.situation[$index]">
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-class` basically just a way to dynamically manipulate the classes in HTML. For your scenario, your div will has the class `has-error` if the validation got error or `field.hasError === true`. For more information, you can refer to [ways to user NgClass](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-many-ways-to-use-ngclass).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ng-class="{true: 'has-error'}[field.hasError]"
```

Basically, it just means that if `field.hasError === true` then  `has-error` class is just applied to the element.

Comment: Ty, now I understand what that means!